# Magento 1.3.4 --> 1.5.1 upgrade. Dev site updated...how to upgrade live site?

Tags: magento, upgrade

So, we had the hosting service set up a dev site with the intentions to then upgrade our live site once that was done.  After a ton of back and forth the hosting service bailed on us, and we're left with an updated dev site and not much of a clue on how to update the live site.

While I'm not asking for a foolproof way of updating the live site, I do need something that won't impact sales by being down....or something that won't be a problem to roll back on in case there's issues.

any guidance / tutorials would be a big help.  when I set up our original site we weren't live yet, so I could grind away without losing $$$.  That's not the case now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that happen for upgrades: new functionality from the updated / additional files themselves, and database upgrades which are triggered by each module's version.

**Above all, it may be advisable to find a freelancer or shop with a good Magento track record and experience in 1.3 to >= 1.4 upgrades. They should be able to set you up for the clearest upgrade path moving forward.** That said, here's a procedure:

1. Backup database and filesystem.
2. Perhaps, make another backup.
3. Create your own dev environment from this backup: install files, duplicate database, change the db settings in `app/etc/local.xml`. You *likely* will need only to change the **base_url** settings in the `core_config_data` table: `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE %base_url`).
4. Check the big core files: Diff your app/code/core/*, js/*, lib/* files with a known-good copy of the 1.3.2.4 or 1.3.3 (there is no 1.3.4) - check Mage::getVersion(). Any changes will need to be accounted for. And slap whoever changed them :-)
5. Once you've verified that you have a healthy core / fixed your core, you are ready to test the upgrade. Simply copy the files from 1.5.1 over.
6. Make sure that you have set a substantial timeout if you have lots of orders.

If you have issues with this upgrade, you may opt to step through versions. Particularly, you can go from 1.3.2.4 to 1.4.0.0 to 1.4.2.0 to 1.5.1.0. At the very least, this might help you spot where along the upgrade sequence things are going to pot.

Also, you will need to fix your templates. Between 1.3 and 1.4 Magento implemented a base design package and default theme; other themes should build from this. You'll almost certainly need to merge your changes from your layout templates (under template/page/; 1column.phtml, etc.).

Comment: and here I was hoping to jump from 1.3 --> 1.5 directly :)  we're on 1.3.2.4, which works fine but with Google changing their product requirements we've been forced into upgrading.  And probably for the best.  What's a bit annoying is that the dev site was set up for 1.5.1 and works, but every thing I've tried to do to move that to a sub directory seems to throw the URL back to the dev site, which also them points to the live site at some point.  Kooky.

Comment: RE: url - just check core_config_data table for ...path LIKE "%base_url" and ...path LIKE "%base_link_url". Also, check in .htaccess for rewrites. I would recommend setting up your dev instance under a different folder entirely, not as a subfolder to the current site.